# Injective map between same dimension implies bijectivity?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

For an injective map between two spaces with the same dimension, does the map need to be linear in order to be bijective?

In other words, if this statement universally true:

> For any function, injectivity between same dimension implies bijectivity.

or it is true only for linear functions:

> For linear functions, injectivity between same dimension implies bijectivity.

It seems I got some counter example for non-linear functions. So I am primarily interested in if it is true for linear functions.

Comment: What about the function that sends $(x,y)$ to $(x^3,y^3)$

Comment: So, it needs to be linear, right? Thanks @Amr

Comment: No it does not. The example I gave is not a linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: I mean, only for linear functions, injectivity between same dimension implies bijectivity?

Comment: I got your question. (It is different from the one being stated above)

Comment: Is your question the following: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear injective map, does $f$ need to be surjective ?

Comment: No, I was asking if this statement " injectivity between same dimension implies bijectivity" is universally true, or true only for linear functions.

Comment: Oh @Amr, actually you are right. I am asking what you said - given I got counter example for nonlinear functions. Thanks and apologize for the confusion!

Comment: @Amr - I edited, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can send $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ injectively and not bijectively. (It is a bijection to $(-1,1)$).

$x\mapsto\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x)$

Now, for linear functions it can also be false. Imagine vector spaces of the same infinite dimension. $S:\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^2$ defined by $S(a_1,a_2,\ldots):=(0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)$ is linear, injective but not bijective.

For linear functions between vector spaces of the same **finite** dimension then, it is true.

To prove this use the fundamental theorem of linear algebra. See where the function sends a basis of the space.

Comment: Tanks Franklin, so only for linear functions, injectivity between same dimension implies bijectivity, right?

Comment: Linear is a sufficient condition (for finite dimension). It also not necessary. You can have **some** non-linear injections that are bijections too.

Comment: Yeah, I could image. Like $f(x) = x^3$.